# how to sum columns from 2 tables by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
table1 contains (amount, date)
table2 contains (amount, revenue, date)
```

I need to:

```
sum table1.amount + table2.amount, sum table2.revenue
according to table1.date and table2.date
```

like:

```
select sum(table1.amount + table2.amount), sum(table2.revenue)
from table1,table2
where table1.date and table2.date = '2008-02%'
```

Comment: What should happen if there is a row in table 1 with date '2008-02-01' but no corresponding row in table 2, or vice versa?

Comment: You want this for all records in February, 2008?

Comment: Yeah i want feb 2008 records, if null then data should show null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the result for all year-month:

```
with table3 (amount, revenue, date) as
(
    select amount, 0, date from table1
    union all
    select cost, revenue, date from table2
)
select year(date), month(date), sum(amount), sum(revenue)
from table3
group by year(date), month(date)
order by year(date), month(date);
```

Comment: alright i forgot to tell that the column name "amount" in table 2 is actually named "cost". and i run this it's not displaying the right data for amount. but the revenue is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(revenue)
FROM (
        SELECT amount, 0 as revenue, theDate 
        FROM table1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT amount, revenue, theDate 
        FROM table2 ) AS DERIVED
WHERE   (MONTH(DERIVED.theDate) = 2 
AND YEAR(DERIVED.theDate) = 2008)
```

You could put the where clause in the UNION statement, which I probably would but this simplifies things for the example.  If you have keys in the equation I'd do this differently with a full outer join or something like that but for your example this works.

If you want the date to show and view the sums for all the dates then the following would work:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(revenue), theDate 
FROM (
        SELECT amount, 0 as revenue, theDate 
        FROM table1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT amount, revenue, theDate 
        FROM table2 ) AS DERIVED
GROUP BY theDate
```

Hope that helps!